# Returning a partial array from another array Javascript ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, standards

I would like to return a formated partial array from a larger original array using ES6 syntax:

**Original Array**

```
const books = [
    { id: 22, valid: false },
    { id: 7, valid: true },
    { id: 14, valid: false },
    { id: 1, valid: true },
]
```

**New Array**

```
const booksIds = [7, 1]
```

**Gist**

```
const validBooksIds = bookIds.map(book => book.valid ? book.id : null);
```

Anyone have any sugar?

Comment: Did you mean `const bookIds = [7, 1]`?

Comment: Yes, thats is correct. Updated the answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would filter, then map:

```js
const books = [
  {id:22, valid:false},
  {id: 7, valid: true}, // keep this
  {id:14, valid:false},
  {id: 1, valid: true}  // keep this
];

const validBookIds = books.filter(b => b.valid).map(b => b.id);

console.log(validBookIds);
```

Comment: Selecting this as the answer simply because its verbose, readable AND has an example.

Comment: [*Verbose*](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=define+verbose&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=tABhV8G0LsWk0ATdg73oBw)? Perhaps you meant [*concise*](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=define+verbose&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=tABhV8G0LsWk0ATdg73oBw#q=define+concise). :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
const books = [
    { id: 22, valid: false },
    { id: 7, valid: true },
    { id: 14, valid: false },
    { id: 1, valid: true },
]

const validBooksIds = books.filter((it) => it.valid).map((it) => it.id)
```

Comment: Can someone explain why this answer is better than the accepted answer? We both independently posted the same answer within 20 seconds of one another, but there seems to be an unusual disparity in votes.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce can do it in one:

```js
const books = [
    { id: 22, valid: false },
    { id: 7, valid: true },
    { id: 14, valid: false },
    { id: 1, valid: true },
]
  
var bookIds = books.reduce((a,b)=>{if(b.valid) a.push(b.id); return a},[]); 

console.log(bookIds);
```

Which can be reduced to:

```
var bookIds = books.reduce((a,b)=>b.valid? a.push(b.id) && a : a,[]);
```

but that may be getting a little obfuscated.

You might also create your own sugar with a *filterMap* method of Array and use that:

```
Array.prototype.filterMap = function(filterFn, mapFn) {
  return this.filter(filterFn).map(mapFn);
}

console.log(books.filterMap(b=>b.valid,b=>b.id));
```

Probably needs a few checks but you get the idea. ;-)

Comment: Yes obviously the best approach for this for this particular case is reduce. Basically i believe the following is the most boiled down form of the reduce approach though. `bookIds = books.reduce((a,b) => b.valid && a.concat(b.id) || a, []);`

Comment: @Redu What makes reduce the obvious choice?

Comment: @4castle Three basic reasons, 1) reduce finishes the job in O(n) time 2) it's totally self contained and won't interfere with anything other than the ones included within it's own definition. 3) It returns the result so you can chain it for a proper functional continuum. Nothing but a beauty here.

Comment: @Redu Nice! But `filterMap` has all those properties too. Which do you prefer?

Comment: @4castle filter map combo is another functional way of doing the job. It also complies with being self contained and returning the result; yet it has O(2n) time complexity. Which means the code has to go through the array twice up until it produces the result while in reduce method it can produce the result in just one pass. Well does it make a huge difference..? I guess not.